# Communication between 2 arduino's one at 6th floor and the other at the basement

Tags: esp8266, communication

Communication between 2 Arduino's one at 6th floor and the other at the basement.

I tried with nodemcu , but the signal is not reaching the basement. From 6th floor.

[image]

Which is the best way to connect?.

I have a couple of nRF24L01 with antennas, does nRF24L01 works in this case?

How about hc-12. I have seen tests with line of sight's only.  But in this case, I have an elevation of about 80 feet and also some horizontal distance.

Basically, I wanted to implement wireless water level measurement for our overhead tank inside our apartment.

Regards
ravi

Comment: 2.4 GHz radio is too short range.  Try 433 MHz modules instead.

Comment: lora will work if nothing else does. you can get ESP8266 boards with antenna jacks. using a shotgun antenna on the roof will almost assuredly connect to the basement once aimed.